# How to generate different json files from fire-base for different product flavors Android

Tags: android, json, firebase

How to generate different json files from fire-base for different product flavors **Android**

I have added product flavor in **gradle** file but i don't have any idea about generate Google json file from **firebase**.

Comment: Does your app have different appId for different flavors?

Comment: yes @Swayangjit

Comment: i have 4 different appid

Comment: The best answer I've found for this is on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66739849/3970630)

Answer (score 0):

Create a different app using different product flavour on firebase project. Place respective json files in product flavour directory.

Comment: Inside the project or i need to create other project with different flavor and different name.
Than you for reply.

Comment: I have created different app with different flavor but it's not working it give flavor missing error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different app with different flavor within the same project..

Comment: I have applied your solution but still same error occurred